# Incorrect range height, was 1 but should be 344 - when trying to take range to another sheet using .setValues()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, setvalue

I am trying to loop through a range of data, look for a certain value in the first column of data and then copy all rows with that value into another sheet called "Closed Requests"

```
function copyToClosed(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Open Requests");
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var datarange = sheet.getRange(10,2,lastrow-1, 50).getValues();
  var row = 10;
  var x = [];

  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Closed Requests"
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);

  for (i=0;i<datarange.length;i++) {

      if(i[0] == "CC") {
        x.push([datarange[i]])
      }
  var targetRange = 
  targetSheet.getRange
  (targetSheet.getLastRow()+1,2,datarange.length,datarange[0].length)
  targetRange.setValues(x)

  }
}
```

As you can see I first define the datarange and create an array "x". Then I loop through the data to find the text "CC" in the first column of the range. Then I push those rows into the array and copy them onto the sheet "Closed Requests" by using .setValues(). I get the error message at .setValues()

Browsing through other occurrences of this error I figured that there must be a problem with the dimension of my array and that I incorrectly defined either the array or the range. However I cannot figure out what exactly there seems to be the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1st shouldn't i[0] be datarange[i][0] and 2nd shouldn't datarange.length and datarange[0].length be x.length and x[0].length, and 3rd shouldn't there be a closing } before var targetRange =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors are in the for loop. Try this:

```
function copyToClosed(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Open Requests");
 var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
 var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
 var datarange = sheet.getRange(10,2,lastrow-1, 50).getValues();
 var row = 10;
 var x = [];
 var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Closed Requests"
 var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
 for (i=0;i<datarange.length;i++) {
      if(datarange[i][0] == "CC") {
       x.push(datarange[i])
     }}  
 targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1,2,x.length,x[0].length).setValues(x)
 }
```

Comment: If this works for you, could you please approve the answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that might work is you could have it run on a onEdit so when the value is changed to CC it would auto move the row. you could do that using the following code

```
    function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Active
  // target sheet of move to named Found 
  // test column with yes/no is col 13 or M
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Open Requests" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == 'CC') {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Closed Requests");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }

}
```